# apply password in cfspreadsheet with multiples sheets

Tags: excel, coldfusion, cfml

how to protect the two sheets? currently the code only protects the first sheet.

```
var plan = spreadsheetNew("TEST", true);
SpreadsheetCreateSheet(plan , "TEST2" );
cfspreadsheet(
  action="write", fileName="temp.xslx", name="plan", 
  overwrite=true, sheetname="TEST", password="123"
);
```

I also tested omitting the sheet name in cfspreadsheet

```
cfspreadsheet(action="write", fileName="temp.xslx", name="plan", overwrite=true, password="123");
```

Comment: Does this code actually produce a file with two sheets?  If so, passwords generally apply to the entire file, not individual sheets.

Comment: @DanBracuk No, password is applying only to the current sheet(which is the first one).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of CF are you using? Because the original code *doesn't* password protect any sheet for me with CF2018. The sheet opens right up without prompting...

Comment: @SOS CF21. Excel will open but the content will not be editable until the password is entered.. but it works even in CF11.

Comment: @JonathanCominRibeiro - Ahh, thanks. I don't use that feature often and was expecting it to prompt before opening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**(based on comments)

If you want to be able to change selected sheet I would revert back to your code and then use the internal Java libraries to set passwords.

```
plan = spreadsheetNew("TEST", true);
SpreadsheetCreateSheet(plan , "TEST2" );
workbookJavaObj = plan.getWorkBook();
workbookJavaObj.getSheetAt(0).protectSheet('123');
workbookJavaObj.getSheetAt(1).protectSheet('123');
spreadsheetSetActiveSheet(plan, "TEST2");
cfspreadsheet(
  action="write", fileName="temp.xlsx", name="plan", overwrite=true
);
```

**Coldfusion solution**

I think this is how it should be done. Create a new spreadsheet object and utilize the `action="update"` to add that sheet in to the file which was written earlier.

```
plan = spreadsheetNew("TEST", true);
cfspreadsheet(action="write", fileName="temp.xlsx", name="plan", overwrite=true, sheetname="TEST", password="123");
plan2 = spreadsheetNew("TEST2", true);
cfspreadsheet(action="update", fileName="temp.xlsx", name="plan2", sheetname="TEST2", password="123");
```

Comment: and how it would work if I need to do this: SpreadSheetSetActiveSheet(plan, "TEST2"); ?
would I need to write all the content to the TEST2 sheet first and then update the file?

Comment: thanks, the first part manipulating with the java lib was what I needed